# Fourier Transformation if we only have relative coordinates

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, fourier-transform, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

Let’s say we want to do a Fourier Transformation (FT) of a function $f(t-t‘,r-r‘)$ i.e. the function to be Fourier transformed only depends on relative coordinates. This is for example the case if we have a translational invariant space and time.

**My question is:**

If we do the FT we will get two delta functions like $\delta (\omega-\omega‘) \delta (k-k‘)$. It is clear to me why this is the case, but I am not able to proof it mathematically. Can someone help me out?

**Additional question:**

Because of invariant space and time our functions only depend on $r-r‘$ and $t-t‘$. It is conceptually clear to me why this is the case. But is there a mathematical proof for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question can be answered by simple substitution:

$$\int f(t-t')e^{-iwt -iw't'}dtdt' = \int f(\tau)e^{-i\tau\omega}e^{-it'(\omega-\omega')}d\tau dt' = 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega')\int f(\tau)e^{-i\tau\omega}d\tau,$$
where $\tau=t-t'$ and we used $\int e^{-itx}dt = 2\pi\delta(x)$.

For the second question see the comment.

EDIT: Sorry I missread that comment, it doesn't answer your second question.

Ok, so lets assume translation symmetry, such that $f(r,r') = f(r+a,r'+a)$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R^n}$. Define $R=r-r'$. Then
$$f(r,r') = f(R+r',r') = f(R,0)\equiv f(R),$$
where I used the translation symmetry in the second step.